# Assign function loop value to variable in python

Tags: python, list, function, assign

I would like to assign the result of this function in a variable as a string

```
def fib(n): 
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

fib(100)
```

...prints from 1 to 89

I would like to assign the output to x as in the example:

```
x = fib(100)
```

Comment: Instead of `print`, use `return`.

Comment: There is a difference between *printing* and *returning*...

Comment: Irfan434 is correct, however you may also need to put all the numbers into a string as they're generated, then return the string. On which point, are you wanting to return a list of numbers or a string?

Comment: so after the function runs i want to return the output as a string

Comment: When defining a function, consider that it is far easier to create a string from whatever the function returns than it is to extract anything from a pre-made string. Also, defer things like printing as long as possible.

Comment: so, in this example how do i do this?

Comment: In this example, at the start of the function you should define an empty string: ```output = ""```. Then, instead of printing the character, you want to add it to the string, so instead of ```print(a, end=' ')``` you want ```output += a + " "``` (you need to add a space there as well, so that all the numbers are separated.) And finally, instead of ```print()``` at the end, you want to return the output, so do ```return output```